# Need to convert time to h:m:s

Tags: python, pandas

I have time formats with missing hours like  36:21 or incompleted hour format like 1:23:30, would like to convert it to standard time format like 00:00:00, 
but I don't know why my code did not work.

Need to convert time format H: M:S like this --> 00:00:00
len(x) == 6 i.e. 36:21 ; len(x) == 7 i.e. 1:23:30

## want to get     00:36:21 and 01:23:30

```
for x in df7[' Chip Time']:
    if len(x) == 6: 
        x = '00:'+ x
    elif len(x) == 7:
        x = '0'+ x
    print (df7[' Chip Time'])
```

===========================================================
Support needed. Thank you!

Comment: len is `5` and `7` and  you don't assign back to `df7`

Answer (score 0):

you should use apply method, it is much faster than iteration

also i recommend you to read https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-pad-strings-with-zero-space-or-some-other-character/

this should work:

`df7[' Chip Time'] = df7[' Chip Time'].apply(lambda x : x.rjust(5, '0').rjust(6, ':').rjust(8, '0'))`